# Bootstrap - Footer beng overlapped by main content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

***Question background:***

I'm pretty new to Bootstrap and have been developing a site as of late and have run into an issues with the content of my page 'overlapping' the footer at the bottom when the window is resized to a 'mobile' device resolution.

***The issue:***

The following picture shows a maximized screen with no overlap.
[image]

Re-sized screen, footer overlap:

[image]

***HTML:***

I have a 'master page' which holds the footer, each page implements this.

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="padding">
                <h2>C#</h2>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span4">
                        <h3>Project1</h3>
                        @ViewBag.ProjectTwoInfo
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                        <h3>Project1</h3>
                        @ViewBag.ProjectOneInfo
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                        <h3>Project1</h3>
                        @ViewBag.ProjectOneInfo
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 cSharpBackGroundColour">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class=" paddingTop">
                        <div class="span3 circle-image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3 circle-image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3 circle-image">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***EDIT:***

**Footer code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="author" content="Martin Bean" />
<link href="\Bootstrap\css\bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="\Bootstrap\css\bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="\Bootstrap\css\bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="\Bootstrap\css\bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="\CustomCSS\Footer.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="\CustomCSS\HeroUnit.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="\Bootstrap\FontAwesome\css\font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="\Bootstrap\FontAwesome\css\font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="\Scripts\jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="\Bootstrap\js\bootstrap.js"></script>
<title>Twitter&rsquo;s Bootstrap with Ryan Fait&rsquo;s Sticky Footer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    footer {
        color: #666;
        background: #222;
        padding: 17px 0 18px 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #000;
        height: auto;
    }

    .colour {
        background-color: #272727;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .imageCentering {

        align-content:center;
    }

    footer a {
        color: #999;
    }

        footer a:hover {
            color: #efefef;
        }

    .wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto -63px;
        background-color: white;
    }

    .wrapper2 {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        margin-left: 250px;
        margin-right: 250px;
        padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    }

    .title {
        margin-top: 40px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        color: white;
        font-size: x-large;
    }

    .push {
        height: 90px;
    }

    .pushtop {
        height: 5px;
    }
    /* not required for sticky footer; just pushes hero down a bit */
    .wrapper > .container {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .buttonAlign {
        align-content: center;
    }

    .floatLeft {
        float: left;
    }

    .floatRight {
        float: right;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">

        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>

        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="/Blogs/All">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/About">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        Projects
                        <b class=" caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownmenu">
                        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Proj1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Proj2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Proj3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@*</div>*@
<div class="colour">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="title">
            Software Developer@*</div>*@
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">

        @RenderBody()
    </div>

<div class="push"></div>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="floatLeft">
                    <a><ul>About Me</ul></a>
                    <a><ul>Projects</ul></a>
                    <a><ul>Contact Me</ul></a>
                </div>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-3x"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**Any help resolving this issue would be great. Please note I would also want the 'grey' background div - that holds the 3 images to be responsive.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Footer on Bottom of Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610694/css-footer-on-bottom-of-page)

Comment: the main part of the problem (the footer) isn't showing in you code

Comment: Need to see the css to be able to help but it's most likely a float issue.

Comment: This code is bootstrap 2 not 3.

Comment: @Fabio Added the Footer html/css

Comment: @joshhunt Code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have several HTML code issues, I did a clean-up and also simplified things a bit for demo purposes (you may adjust at will, of course).

The HTML part:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner"> <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>

        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="/Blogs/All">About</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="/About">Contact</a>

                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        Projects
                        <b class=" caret"></b>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownmenu">
                        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Proj1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Proj2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Proj3</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="colour">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="title">Software Developer</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="lipsum">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum imperdiet rutrum leo quis aliquam. Sed pretium efficitur enim at ultricies. Nullam ullamcorper porta risus, quis imperdiet eros rutrum sit amet. Nullam in nisl bibendum, dignissim arcu quis, consectetur turpis. Cras luctus egestas ligula. Suspendisse dignissim diam a augue egestas pharetra. Donec viverra eu velit ut pharetra. Nulla suscipit, ante eget venenatis cursus, nulla erat congue tellus, faucibus cursus orci lacus sit amet urna. Nulla facilisi. Duis commodo porttitor sem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer dui elit, rhoncus vitae tincidunt nec, scelerisque ac dolor. Integer at ligula eget ligula scelerisque volutpat eget quis lorem.</p>
        <p>Praesent ac sapien sit amet magna sollicitudin vestibulum et nec erat. Quisque consectetur vel dui ac dapibus. Praesent at sapien tristique augue tincidunt auctor sed non justo. Fusce ac venenatis mauris. Quisque lobortis neque a eros hendrerit consectetur ac id magna. Mauris non velit ante. Nunc orci lorem, auctor a orci a, luctus sollicitudin turpis. Phasellus ornare tempus felis eu pharetra.</p>
        <p>Integer eleifend, sapien eu molestie tristique, nunc felis varius tellus, at congue magna sapien ut tortor. Maecenas sodales ultricies ligula sollicitudin cursus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent laoreet odio ex, ut luctus tortor mollis sit amet. Aenean rutrum consequat lorem eget porta. Aliquam lacus enim, congue ac condimentum sit amet, consequat a diam. Duis eget mauris id nisi molestie vulputate sit amet vel nulla. Curabitur ac feugiat enim, eu rutrum magna.</p>
        <p>Suspendisse sed lorem ac leo volutpat sodales. Pellentesque erat ex, tincidunt eu urna ac, gravida convallis eros. Phasellus nisl purus, egestas quis ipsum id, ornare pharetra tellus. Nullam congue leo ex, nec sagittis dolor tempor nec. Sed convallis sem risus, a congue leo feugiat non. Integer placerat dui eget lorem eleifend, a gravida tortor tempus. Vestibulum at est tempor sem sollicitudin hendrerit. Etiam vitae mauris eget sapien pharetra mattis a quis metus. Mauris facilisis sapien non fringilla scelerisque. Fusce a odio ultricies, rutrum nunc quis, faucibus quam.</p>
        <p>Donec sed est vitae elit dignissim gravida. Vivamus blandit eros ex, vel placerat dui ornare in. Nullam feugiat risus lectus. Cras sagittis dolor vitae vulputate accumsan. Sed arcu massa, tempor vel massa nec, vehicula pellentesque tortor. Suspendisse fringilla eros risus, a scelerisque neque tempor ut. In et velit sapien. Etiam porttitor aliquam arcu, ut mollis augue rutrum feugiat.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="push"></div>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12 links">
                <div class="floatLeft"> <a>About Me</a>
 <a>Projects</a>
 <a>Contact Me</a>

                </div>
                <div class="floatRight"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

You had those `<UL>` elements before the footer's `<A>` and also an additional closing `</div>` on all sections. With the HTML cleaned, CSS is as simple as this:

```
.links .floatLeft a {
    padding:30px;
    background:#fc0;
}
footer, .wrapper, .push {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfLuu0u0/) for complete code and preview